# Android - multiple vertical scrollviews in horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

In my app I have a horizontal scrollview. Inside that HSV I add dynamically various VERTICAl scrollviews (of different size). Now only the first vertical scrollview is accessible as I cant do the horizontal scroll ( the child wins the touch).

Any suggestions on how to make the parent HSV respond to horizontal gestures and the children vertical scrollviews respond to vertical gestures?

Thanks in advance

Comment: add the layout code in your Q -- anyway without looking at the code what you can try is wrap each  scrollview with a framelayout e.g = (<FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"> scrollview_layout </FrameLayout>) try that and see if it helps. if your layout is something like a fruit machine the use (wrap_content) for the height